# Addressing a person in mail, person has a title

Tags: traducción, saludos, formalidad

I would like to address a person with a medical Dr. title formally in mail. In English it is simple, just adding the title: "Dear Dr. X." In German, on the other hand, it is a bit more complex: I also need to add a proper gender prefix (Herr or Frau): "Sehr geehrter Herr Dr X" or "Sehr geehrte Frau Dr X".

How is it done in Spanish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated on wikipedia

> Formal salutations. Only written.
>
> - "Estimado" (+ name or title "Señor". "Sr." is the abbreviation). For    male. Example for a man called Juan García: "Estimado Juan" or
> - "Estimado Sr. García". The last is more formal.
> - "Estimada" (+ name or title "Señora". "Sra." is the abbreviation). For female. Example for a woman called Ana Sánchez:
> - "Estimada Ana" or "Estimada Sra. Sánchez". The last is more formal.
> - "Estimados amigos" (plural) When your letter is addressed to a group of people.
> - "Estimado amigo" or "Querido amigo" (male or unknown gender). You may or not know the name of the person.
> - "Estimada amiga" or "Querida amiga" (female).
> - "Estimadas amigas" (a group of females).
> - "Excelentísimo Señor" (+name or without it) or "Excelentísima Señora" (female). This is extremely formal and is usually reserved
>     for certain formal procedures with the government. You can also use
>     "Ilustrísimo" (male) or "Ilustrísima" (female) instead of
>     "Excelentísimo".

Sr. or Sra. include the gender, so there is no need to add an extra word as 'Frau'.

If he/she has the title Dr. / Dra. , then it should be added instead of Sr. / Sra.

*Summarizing*: A formal way to address can be 'Estimado/Estimada' + 'Dr.'/'Dra'/ or 'Sr.' /'Sra' or (highest rank) + surname

*Ref:*

http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salutation#Spanish

Answer (score 4):

In Spanish the proper way is `Dr.` (male) or `Dra.` (female). Both are abbreviations of `doctor` and `doctora`, respectively. If you use the whole word, it can be used in lower case, but if you use the abbreviation, it is used in upper case, even in the middle of a sentence. In all cases, the title is followed by the person's surname.

Examples:

> - Tengo que concertar una cita con la doctora López.
>
> - El Dr. Ibáñez no puede atenderle hoy.
>
> - ¿Dónde es la conferencia del doctor Carreras?

The use of `doctor` replaces the use of `señor` or `don`, so you must not use things like *señor doctor don*, as it could sound like you are mocking the person alluded.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write "Querido Doctor (o Doctora) X"

Comment: Unlike the English `Dear`, Spanish `Querido` is reserved for people you have a genuine affection for. I would always say `Estimado Doctor Lastname` or `Querido Firstname.` It's difficult to think of a situation where someone might use `Querido Doctor,` though it's not impossible, perhaps for someone suffering from a long illness where they have built up a relationship. Then wih `Querido` I'd use the firstname, but keep the `Doctor` for respect also.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you for pointing that out.