# Should I use querido, estimado, or distinguido in an email to a teacher?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, formalidad, correspondencia

I have been sending emails to my teacher using:

> Querido,  ...

I recently found out that *estimado* and *distinguido* also mean "dear". Which form of "dear" should I use in an email (to my teacher)?

Comment: You might be interested in the answers here https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16845/addressing-a-person-in-mail-person-has-a-title/16849#16849 to a slightly different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estimado = Esteemed.
Distinguido = Distinguished.

Neither term means "dear."  Also, at least in Spain, "querido" is only used for family members and people you love.

For a teacher I would choose "*estimado*", and for someone who is a very very important person "*distinguido*".

I would comment to that teacher and have them clarify what they prefer.

Comment: _estimado_ equals esteemed, not estimated in this context. However esteemed is archaic unlike _estimado_.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey for the clarification.

Comment: In Chile you may use querido or estimado, depending on your level of acquaintance. Distinguido would come out as too formal.

Answer (score 2):

Son tres sentimientos distintos relacionados con distintas personas.

**Querido**(s) son las personas por las que uno siente aprecio/ternura/cariño/amor... como una madre, un novio o un viejo conocido.

**Estimado**(s) son las personas por las que se siente aprecio. Son gentes valoradas positivamente. : Estimados amigos, compañeros, alumnos, etc... es una fórmula de cortesía

**Distinguido**(s) es aún mas formal y viene a representar a los "escogidos" de entre los demás, los que sobresalen, los más respetables.

Querido y estimado son más proximos. Distinguido es más formal y respetuoso